# centos 6 epel alternative repository replacement

Tags: centos6, rpm, epel

I've installed EPEL repository already on my server. I wanted to install something new and I get this error with yum :

`PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
    Trying other mirror.
    Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: CentALT. Please verify its path and try again`

When I checked the EPEL (editor note: actually CentALT but leaving original for clarity) url , I got this error with the [url](http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml) :

```
403 Forbidden - nginx
```

So I decided to change EPEL source . I went through the steps at `http://howto.wikin.com/wiki/How_to_Delete_Centos_Repositories` to remove previous repository and when i do `yum repolist` getting this :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.gtcomm.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.
repo id         repo name                                                 status
CentALT         CentALT Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64          0
base            CentOS-6 - Base                                           0
extras          CentOS-6 - Extras                                         0
mariadb         MariaDB                                                   0
updates         CentOS-6 - Updates                                        0
repolist: 0
```

Now, when I want to install the EPEL repository with this command:

`sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

still getting this error :

`Retrieving http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
    Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed`

How can I get the EPEL repo installed?

Comment: Since you are having trouble with the centalt repository, why are you bothering with the EPEL repository?

Comment: cause i want to intall `proftpd` and i found it on epel.what's your solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reinstall the EPEL repository run a `yum reinstall` for the `.rpm` of that repo.

```
yum reinstall 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
```

Answer (score 6):

You're attributing the problem to the wrong repository. The error is for the CentALT repository. It does appear to be out of commission at this point (returning 403s). The solution in this case would be to remove the CentALT repository and run `yum clean all`.
As far as EPEL not appearing in the repository list see what happens after you run `yum clean all`. It appears that it is still installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks Jacob , i removed CentALT .but i can't see EPEL repo in the list while it says " package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed" .